# Git - commit html + js files in the same folder

Tags: git, version-control

I have a project set up in WebStorm with Git as source control. I created a folder which contains two types of files: html and js.
Structure is like this:

```
file1.html
file1.js
file2.html
file2.js
```

When I try to commit the files, or the folder entirely, it only includes in the commit the html files. I can't commit/push the js files to the repository.
Is it supoosed to behave like this or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Are the js files ignored? what does a `git check-ignore -v -- file1.js` return?

Comment: if you don't have git check-ignore; check the contents of any .gitignore file in your git repository if it contains a pattern that matches .js files (eg `*.js`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably .js files are ignored in your git repository. check any `.gitignore` file in you git repository and remove that pattern. Probably there is a line like this:

```
*.js
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you! I've just started working with Git and didn't know about this:)